# Org: Agenda command with org-agenda-filter-by-tag not working

Tags: org-mode

I have the following agenda command for things that I want to do at home:

```
     ("h" "thing TODO at Home"
     (

      (tags-todo "+dailies+SCHEDULED<=\"<today>+1\"")
      (agenda "" ((org-agenda-ndays 1)
                  (org-agenda-filter-by-tag  '("-work" ))
                  (org-agenda-sorting-strategy
                   (quote ((agenda time-up priority-down tag-up) )))
                  (org-deadline-warning-days 0)
                  ))
      (tags "reading")
      (tags "writing")
      (tags-todo "REFILE")


      )

     )
```

I am using `org-agenda-filter-by-tag` to remove all the entries that are tagged work. (I have some file
wide tags on the files). However, the agenda works, but is showing me also the entries tagged `work`.
I also tried putting the `org-agenda-filter-by-tag` on the top of the definition of the block agenda
but it is also not working.

Org-mode: 8.3.2
Emacs 24.5.1
OS: Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.4

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first problem is that `org-agenda-filter-by-tag` is a function.  Interactively, this will apply a filter, but in an agenda command like this, you're just assigning a value to it as a variable.  Since functions and variables are in different namespaces, this doesn't cause an error, but it doesn't do anything either.

Unfortunately, the variable you do want, `org-agenda-tag-filter-preset`, is designed to work agenda-wide and can't be usefully set per-block (see the footnote for [this manual entry](http://orgmode.org/manual/Filtering_002flimiting-agenda-items.html)).

If you're okay with having the filter set for the whole agenda, your command should look like this (and I apologize for changing your indentation setup):

```el
("h" "thing TODO at Home"
 ((tags-todo "+dailies+SCHEDULED<=\"<today>+1\"")
  (agenda "" ((org-agenda-ndays 1)
              (org-agenda-sorting-strategy
               (quote ((agenda time-up priority-down tag-up))))
              (org-deadline-warning-days 0)))
  (tags "reading")
  (tags "writing")
  (tags-todo "REFILE"))
 ((org-agenda-tag-filter-preset '("-work"))))
```

If you want work tasks to show up in your `tags` and `tags-todo` blocks, you can use skip functions instead.  For some reason, there is no out-of-the-box skip function for tag filtering, but I wrote one for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33444799/5030424); with that code, your agenda command should look like this:

```el
("h" "thing TODO at Home"
 ((tags-todo "+dailies+SCHEDULED<=\"<today>+1\"")
  (agenda "" ((org-agenda-ndays 1)
              (org-agenda-skip-function
               '(my/org-agenda-skip-without-match "-work"))
              (org-agenda-sorting-strategy
               (quote ((agenda time-up priority-down tag-up))))
              (org-deadline-warning-days 0)))
  (tags "reading")
  (tags "writing")
  (tags-todo "REFILE")))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the clarification. I actually want to remove "-work" tag globally (in all the blocks).  Your proposed solutions gives an error when I use it I changed to  ` (org-agenda-tag-filter-preset '("-work"))`  and it works, if you fix your answer I will mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Fixed.  Sorry about that.  I really should have checked the documentation more closely.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution with the built-in org filtering commands.

This only works if the headline is tagged explicitly. It does not work if the tag is [inherited](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tag-inheritance.html)

```
(agenda ""
        ((org-agenda-skip-function
          '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'regexp ":work:"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Joe's excellent answer if you need to skip multiple tags:

```
(agenda ""
    ((org-agenda-skip-function
      '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'regexp ":work1:\\|:work2:"))))
```

in emacs regex `|` OR character needs to be [escaped in its own very special way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443095/what-is-the-or-operator-in-emacs-regexps)

Answer (score 0):

I have used `my/org-agenda-skip-without-match` function but now I'm experiencing sometimes that it won't complete (emacs is stucked). I wasn't able to get know what is wrong.

I have found some more simple function at [list.gnu.org](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2012-12/msg00288.html)

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
;;; Based on http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/41427
  (defun my-skip-tag(tag)
    "Skip entries that are tagged TAG"
    (let* ((entry-tags (org-get-tags-at (point))))
      (if (member tag entry-tags)
          (progn (outline-next-heading) (point))
        nil)))
#+end_src

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(agenda "" 
 ((org-agenda-skip-function '(my-skip-tag" reward"))
  (org-agenda-overriding-header "Agenda (without rewards: ")))))
#+end_src
```

I have done some changes to be able to match multiple tags

```
(defun my-skip-based-on-tags-and (tags)
  "Skip entries based on the list of TAGS.
   Each element in TAGS should be a cons cell where the car is a sign
   and the cdr is tag. Sign '+' means to skip entries not tagged,
   sign '-' means to skip entries tagged."
  (let* ((entry-tags (org-get-tags-at (point)))
        (should-skip
         (seq-some ; filter that implements logical AND. Use `seq-every-p` for logical OR.
          (lambda (tag-sign)
            (let* ((sign (car tag-sign))    ; "+" or "-"
                   (tag  (cdr tag-sign))    ; name of the tag
                   (tag-found (member tag entry-tags))) ; is the tag at current point?
              (or (and (string= sign "+") (not tag-found)) ; skip if tag not found
                  (and (string= sign "-") tag-found))))   ; skip if tag found
          tags)))
    (when should-skip
      (outline-next-heading)
      (point))))
```

in agenda you would call it like this:

```
(agenda "" (
          (org-agenda-skip-function '(my-skip-based-on-tags-and '(("+" . "tag1")("+" . "tag2"))))
        ))
```